# In the for statement, I was able to get the expected results. But why can not I get the expected results with the while statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, bottle

I'd like to check the operation of '[Web Scraping with Pytho code](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034391.do)' with a web browser. In the for statement, I was able to get the expected results. But the while statement, I can't able to get the expected results.

scrape by tracing the url of wikipedia

**environment**

・Python 3.6.0

・bottle 0.13-dev

・mod_wsgi-4.5.15

**Apache error log**

> No output
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Scraping does not finish processing

**index.py**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bottle import route, view
import datetime
import random
import re

@route('/')
@view("index_template")

def index():
    random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())
    html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
    internalLinks=[]
    links = getLinks("/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
    while len(links) > 0:
        newArticle = links[random.randint(0, len(links)-1)].attrs["href"]
        internalLinks.append(newArticle)
        links = getLinks(newArticle)
    return dict(internalLinks=internalLinks)

def getLinks(articleUrl):
    html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org"+articleUrl)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return bsObj.find("div", {"id":"bodyContent"}).findAll("a", href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))
```

In the for statement, I was able to get the expected results.

Result of web browser output

```
['/wiki/Michael_C._Hall', '/wiki/Elizabeth_Perkins',
 '/wiki/Paul_Erd%C5%91s', '/wiki/Geoffrey_Rush',
 '/wiki/Virtual_International_Authority_File']
```

**index.py**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bottle import route, view
import datetime
import random
import re
@route('/')
@view("index_template")
def index():
    random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())
    html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
    internalLinks=[]
    links = getLinks("/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
    for i in range(5):
        newArticle = links[random.randint(0, len(links)-1)].attrs["href"]
        internalLinks.append(newArticle)
    return dict(internalLinks=internalLinks)
def getLinks(articleUrl):
    html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org"+articleUrl)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return bsObj.find("div", {"id":"bodyContent"}).findAll("a", href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint and tracing your code to see how far it gets? Or at least adding some `print` statements to see what results it's fetching?

Comment: Also, please remove all the code that isn't related to your problem. The wsgi code, the views, etc. They're making it difficult to figure out what should be focused on.

Comment: I remove wsgi code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of your `links` list never reaches `0` so it will continue to run the while loop until the connection times out.

Your for loop works because it is iterating over a `range`, so it will exit once the range maximum is reached.

You never explained why you're using a while loop, but if you want it to exit after a certain number of iterations, you need to use a counter.

```
counter = 0

# this will exit on the 5th iteration
while counter < 5:
    print counter # do something

    counter += 1 # increment the counter after each iteration
```

The preceding will print

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: I misunderstood that the length of the linked list reached 0 as a result of tracing the link

Comment: Just to be clear you don't have a linked list, you have a list of links ;)